# Picture taking up the space left on last (twocolumn, balanced) page

Tags: graphics, two-column

Let's say I have a two-column `scrbook` document, with its last page of each chapter balanced by using the [`balance`](http://ctan.org/pkg/balance) package because `multicol` is not an option for me for reasons that are not part of this question.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{balance}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\balance

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

**Is there some way to fill the remaining space with an image spanning both columns?**

I know this is somewhat awkwardly phrased, but I hope you get the idea of what I am trying. I am aware that this might end up being done completely differently, e.g not using `balance` in the first place, and that is fine for me. But I have to repeat, `multicol` is not an option, and neither is using a different documentclass than `scrbook`. (Mostly because the document, at >500 pages, is mostly layed out, I am applying finishing touches, and doing such fundamental changes at this point will require more re-working than I am willing to apply at this point. Sorry.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This possible solution defines a new figure environment called `figurehere` to suppress the floating property and then seek help from `tikz` via `current page node` skill. Since the exact text height is unknown in advacne, some parameters many need to change accordingly. One may use

1. `current page.north or current page.south`, for example, if the text height is less than or more than 1/2 of the text height.
2. `shift={(x,y)}` can be used as a fine tune once the current page node is determined, which is served as the point of origin. x>0, y>0 is for first quadrant whilst x<0,y<0 would means the 4th quadrant.
3. The `width` and `height` of a graph can also be used as a fine tune parameters.

**Edit:** To elaborate on point 1 and 2, please refer to  [image]

If the center, 0, is selected as the `current page.center` node, then

the upper right corner(A) has    x>0,y>0.    1st quadrant

the upper left corner  (D) has   x<0,y>0.    2nd quadrant

the lower left corner  (C) has  x<0, y<0.    3rd qudarant

the lower right corner (B) has   x>0, y<0.   4rd quadrant

1. If C corner is selected as `current page.south west` node, 
   then the grid area all have x>0, y>0 coordinates.
2. If B corner is selected as `current page.south east` node, 
   then the grid area all have x<0, y>0 coordinates.
3. If A corner is selected as `current page.north east node, 
   then the grid area all have x<0, y<0 coordinates.
4. If D corner is selected as `current page.north west` node, 
   then the grid area all have x>0, y<0 coordinates.

`shift={(x,y)}` follows the same notion to determine a particular position to shift to.

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{figurehere}
{\def\@captype{figure}}
{}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{figurehere}
{\def\@captype{figure}}
{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\balance

\lipsum[2]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=center,shift={(-1.1cm,-2cm)}] at (current page.center) {
\begin{figurehere}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=10cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figurehere}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 probably with `-1.1cm` the image is better positioned.

Comment: Yep, works like a charm... in the MWE. +1. Checkmark will be given as soon as I figure out why it *doesn't* work in my document (where the image is centered on the last line, i.e. the top half rendered on top of the text)... ;-) (I'm a complete Tikz noob, so I have a hard time finding the right thing to tweak. ;-) )

Comment: Would it be possible, for the benefit of Tikz newbies, to elaborate a bit on 1. and 2.? This works, but for me positioning the picture on the page is basically trial & error without really understanding what I'm doing... the parameters to `shift` seem completely un-intuitive to me.

Comment: @karlkoeller -- Indeed, thanks, done accordingly.

Comment: @DevSolar -- Thanks for your patient. Gladly add more info and hope it helps.